# Using variable to a Jquery code

Tags: jquery

I need to change the `eq(0)` and `eq(6)` values to `itemRow` and `itemCol` values.

```
var itemRow = element.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
var itemCol = element.parentNode.cellIndex;

$('#tblItem tbody tr:eq(0) td:eq(6)').text("0.00");
```

This is my current code but it's not working:

```
$('#tblItem tbody tr:eq(' + itemRow + ') td:eq(' + itemCol + 1 + ')').text("0.00");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap `itemCol + 1` in parentheses so it's processed before the concatenation:

```
$('#tblItem tbody tr:eq(' + itemRow + ') td:eq(' + (itemCol + 1) + ')').text("0.00");
```

```js
var itemRow = 1; //element.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
var itemCol = 0; //element.parentNode.cellIndex;

$('#tblItem tbody tr:eq(' + itemRow + ') td:eq(' + (itemCol + 1) + ')').text("0.00");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblItem">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>c</td>
      <td>d</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It worked, can't believe I didn't think of enclosing that to a parenthesis. Thanks man! I'll tag this as accepted once the counter for tagging the answer finishes

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: Awesome username, by the way :)